# How do I output the correct percentages on each bar of my Likert chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, reshape, likert

I'm trying to get my code to output the percentage on top of each individual bar. Right now, the percentages shown below are on the wrong side. My code combines Labels 1 and 2 and Labels 3 and 4, and then outputs those numbers on the incorrect sides.

**Is there a function to label those bars correctly?** I'm including my code, the data from the .csv file, and the current visualization.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(likert)
library(dplyr)

setwd("~/Desktop/")

df <- read.csv("Likert_Test.csv")

df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.factor)
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c("cake?", "cookies?")

df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], factor, levels = 1:4)
myplot <- likert(df[2:3], grouping = df$gender)

plot(myplot, centered = FALSE, col = c("#0A2240", "#3474DA", "#C1A783", "#323A45")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  ggtitle("How much do you like...") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

```
    gender      cake         cookies
    Male        3            1    
    Male        2            2         
    Male        2            2
    Male        4            2
    Male        2            3
    Male        2            3
    Male        2            3
    Male        1            1
    Male        4            2
    Female      1            1
    Female      3            1
    Female      3            4
    Female      3            4
    Female      1            1
    Female      4            3
    Female      4            2
    Female      3            2
    Female      2            1
    Female      3            1
```

Comment: Can you display your dataset example in a reproducible manner as described in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I checked my code and it runs for me. I added my data set in a reproducible manner. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the edited. Sorry for the mistake, I mis-assigned a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample answer - using ggplot without the using the likart package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
df <- readr::read_table("gender      cake         cookies
    Male        3            1    
    Male        2            2         
    Male        2            2
    Male        4            2
    Male        2            3
    Male        2            3
    Male        2            3
    Male        1            1
    Male        4            2
    Female      1            1
    Female      3            1
    Female      3            4
    Female      3            4
    Female      1            1
    Female      4            3
    Female      4            2
    Female      3            2
    Female      2            1
    Female      3            1")

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-gender, names_to = "question", values_to = "values") %>%
  group_by(gender, question) %>%
  count(values) %>%
  mutate(
    level = case_when(values %in% c(3, 4) ~ "high",
                      values %in% c(1, 2) ~ "low",
                      TRUE ~ "NA"),
    values = as.character(values),
    total_n = sum(n),
    pct_low = sum(n[level == "low"]) / sum(n),
    pct_high = sum(n[level == "high"]) / sum(n)
  ) %>%
  print() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, y = n, fill = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = values), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0A2240", "#3474DA", "#C1A783", "#323A45")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(),
                     expand = expand_scale(mult = .05)) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = -.05,
    x = gender,
    label = scales::percent(round(pct_low, 2), accuracy = 1)
  ),
  data = . %>% filter(level == "low")) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = 1.05,
    x = gender,
    label = scales::percent(round(pct_high, 2), accuracy = 1)
  ),
  data = . %>% filter(level == "high")) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ question, nrow = 2) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  labs(title = "How Much do you like...",
       fill = "",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 8
#> # Groups:   gender, question [4]
#>    gender question values     n level total_n pct_low pct_high
#>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <int> <chr>   <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Female cake     1          2 low        10   0.3      0.7  
#>  2 Female cake     2          1 low        10   0.3      0.7  
#>  3 Female cake     3          5 high       10   0.3      0.7  
#>  4 Female cake     4          2 high       10   0.3      0.7  
#>  5 Female cookies  1          5 low        10   0.7      0.3  
#>  6 Female cookies  2          2 low        10   0.7      0.3  
#>  7 Female cookies  3          1 high       10   0.7      0.3  
#>  8 Female cookies  4          2 high       10   0.7      0.3  
#>  9 Male   cake     1          1 low         9   0.667    0.333
#> 10 Male   cake     2          5 low         9   0.667    0.333
#> 11 Male   cake     3          1 high        9   0.667    0.333
#> 12 Male   cake     4          2 high        9   0.667    0.333
#> 13 Male   cookies  1          2 low         9   0.667    0.333
#> 14 Male   cookies  2          4 low         9   0.667    0.333
#> 15 Male   cookies  3          3 high        9   0.667    0.333
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think you need to pass `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` in `geom_bar` and  `geom_text` in order to match the cumulated percentage with the corresponding bar.

Comment: Good call. you mean `position_fill`?

Comment: To my opinion, I will replace `position = "fill"` by `position= position_stack(reverse = TRUE)`. See my answer for an another question of the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369850/overlaying-percentages-on-top-of-individual-bars-in-likert/61370774#61370774

Comment: Updated - I didn't know which values were high/low.

Comment: Yes, it also took me a while to figure it out what labels represents ;)