# Plotting likert scale survey questions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to make a plot of a survey question with a likert scale using ggplots. I need to help to organize the middle  "neutral" values correctly. I have used two data frames, one for the left side "low_col", and one for the right side "high_col", both have the neutral value divided by 2. This is the script I used for the plot, and how the graph looks. I would highly appreciate all the advice to correct the order, and also all the help to add the percentages that I have in both data frames in a column named per. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

```
ggplot()+ geom_bar(data = high_col, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=per, fill=col), position = "stack", stat = "identity")+ geom_bar(data= low_col, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=-per, fill=col), position = "stack", stat = "identity")+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color=c("white"))+coord_flip() +scale_fill_identity("", labels = mylevels, breaks=legend.pal, guide="legend") + theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

The structure of the low_col and high_col is as follows:

For high_col:

```
dput(high_col)
structure(list(Q6 = c("General", "0", "1", "2", "General", "0", "1", "2", "3", "General", "0", "1", "2", "3"), Q75 = c("Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho"), n = c(5, 1, 3, 1, 53, 25, 19, 7, 2, 104, 52, 35, 14, 3), per = c(1.48809523809524, 0.609756097560975, 2.58620689655172, 2.17391304347826, 31.547619047619, 30.4878048780487, 32.7586206896551, 30.4347826086956, 40, 61.9047619047619, 63.4146341463414, 60.3448275862069, 60.8695652173913, 60), col = c("#DFDFDF", "#DFDFDF", "#DFDFDF", "#DFDFDF", "#92C5DE", "#92C5DE", "#92C5DE", "#92C5DE", "#92C5DE", "#0571B0", "#0571B0", "#0571B0", "#0571B0", "#0571B0")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For low_col:

```
dput(low_col)
structure(list(Q6 = c("General", "0", "General", "0", "1", "2", "General", "0", "1", "2"), Q75 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Totalmente insatisfecho",  "Insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho"), class = "factor"), n = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1), per = c(1.19047619047619, 2.4390243902439, 1.48809523809524, 0.609756097560975, 2.58620689655172, 2.17391304347826, 2.38095238095238, 2.4390243902439, 1.72413793103448, 4.34782608695652), col = c("#F4A582", "#F4A582", "#DFDFDF", "#DFDFDF", "#DFDFDF","#DFDFDF", "#CA0020", "#CA0020", "#CA0020", "#CA0020")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")).
```

As a reference, I'm trying to follow two blogs where some individuals already did this kind of likert plots. [In the first](https://rnotr.com/likert/ggplot/barometer/likert-plots/), it uses the color "col" as fill in the geom_bar, however, in my case the order is not working properly. And the result is the graph I've attached.

[In the second blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-plot-likert-scales-with-a-weighted-survey-in-a-dplyr-friendly-way-68df600881a), I used the following script, but I cannot change the colors, nor the order of the legend, as the labels appear in alphabetical order, and the colors are selected by default. Thanks in advance for all the insights, and info.

```
ggplot()+ geom_bar(data = high_col, aes(x=Q6, y=per, fill=Q75), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") + geom_bar(data= low_col, aes(x=Q6, y=-per, fill=Q75), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +coord_flip() + theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100,100, 5), limits = c(-25, 100)) + scale_color_manual(labels=c("Totalmente insatisfecho", "Insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho"), values=legend.pal, guide="legend")+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=left, label=paste(round(left), "%", sep = "")), hjust=2, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=center, label=paste(round(center), "%")), hjust=1, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=right, label=paste(round(right), "%")), hjust=2, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color=c("grey")) + scale_colour_manual("", values = legend.pal, guide="legend")
```

Updated version:
Hi, I have been trying to work this out and with the following code I got the neutral value in the middle, yet the colors do not match.

```
ggplot()+ geom_bar(data = high_col, aes(x=Q6, y=per, fill=Q75), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") + geom_bar(data= low_col, aes(x=Q6, y=-per, fill=Q75), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +coord_flip() + theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100,100, 5), limits = c(-25, 100))+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=left, label=paste(round(left), "%", sep = "")), hjust=2, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=center, label=paste(round(center), "%")), hjust=1, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+geom_text(data = pro_labels, mapping = aes(x=Q6, y=right, label=paste(round(right), "%")), hjust=2, color="white", size=3, position = "stack")+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color=c("grey"))+ scale_fill_discrete(labels= c("Totalmente insatisfecho", "Insatisfecho", "Ni satisfecho, ni insatisfecho", "Satisfecho", "Totalmente satisfecho"))
```

The result is the second graph attached here.[image]

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353320/how-do-i-output-the-correct-percentages-on-each-bar-of-my-likert-chart/61356209#61356209

Comment: Hi OP.  Can you please share the data frames `high_col` and `low_col` via `dput(high_col)` and `dput(low_col)`?  When you input the `dput()` function in your console, your output should start with "`structure(...`".  Just take that text and paste it directly into the question (formatted as code).

Comment: Hi, I added the details of the structure of the low_col and high_col. I will appreciate if you can check the scripts and help me to figure out what is wrong with this ggplot. Thanks so much in advance.